# How to get request headers to be saved to MDC

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-sleuth

I have a spring boot (2.2.5.RELEASE) project with spring-cloud-sleuth (Hoxton.SR3).
I want to send a request to a controller containing a header and for this header to be:

1. Populated in controller's span baggage (i.e. `currentSpan.context().extra()`)
2. Saved to MDC

I have a custom `TracingConfiguration`

```
@Bean
public Tracing tracing(@Value("${spring.application.name}") String serviceName, TracingProperties tracingProperties,
                       CurrentTraceContext currentTraceContext) {

    String profile = String.join(",", env.getActiveProfiles());

    log.info("Enable tracing for service {}", serviceName + ":" + profile);
    return Tracing.newBuilder()
            .localServiceName(serviceName + ":" + profile)
            .currentTraceContext(ThreadLocalCurrentTraceContext.newBuilder()
                    .addScopeDecorator(MDCScopeDecorator.create()) // puts trace IDs into logs
                    .build()
            )
            .sampler(Sampler.NEVER_SAMPLE)
            .propagationFactory(
                    ExtraFieldPropagation.newFactoryBuilder(B3Propagation.FACTORY)
                            .addPrefixedFields(TracingConstant.BAGGAGE_HEADER_PREFIX, tracingProperties.getAllBaggageKeys())
                            .build())
            .build();
}
```

When `tracingProperties.getAllBaggageKeys` return a list of baggage keys read from my configuration file.

I also defined in application.yml:

```yaml
spring:
  sleuth:
    log:
      slf4j:
        whitelisted-mdc-keys:
          - behalf-flow-id
          - behalf-requested-time
          - x-behalf-ach-file-name
          - behalf-principal-id
          - x-http-request-id
          - behalf-principal
          - requestid
    baggage-keys:
      - behalf-flow-id
      - behalf-requested-time
      - x-behalf-ach-file-name
      - behalf-principal-id
      - x-http-request-id
      - behalf-principal
      - requestid
```

When I call (through POSTMAN) the service controller with header with key `baggage-behalf-requested-time` and value `123456` I get in `currentSpan.context().extra()` the value of `baggage-behalf-requested-time` (i.e. `123456`)

Questions

1. Is it right that I need to prefix my header with `baggage-`? Isn't the framework suppose to handle it by itself? Or it just do it when I send a request with Spring itself (i.e. `RestTemplate`)?
2. Why MDC is not populated with the value of `baggage-behalf-requested-time` header?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have your custom tracing mechanism, that's why you need to take care of all the `baggage-` prefixing etc. If you check out the 2.2.2.RELEASE of Sleuth, you'll see that we do prefix those fields ourselves https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-sleuth/blob/v2.2.2.RELEASE/spring-cloud-sleuth-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/sleuth/autoconfig/TraceAutoConfiguration.java#L168-L174 Then, they get also populated to the MDC (https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-sleuth/blob/v2.2.2.RELEASE/spring-cloud-sleuth-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/sleuth/log/Slf4jScopeDecorator.java) but without the `baggage-` prefix. In the latest release (2.2.3.RELEAE) the code got refactored but conceptually it's similar.

Comment: I removed my custom tracing mechanism (Since Sleuth's one give me the same functionality) and now it seems to work. Thanks you!

Comment: If I have e baggage-key (defined in application.yml) that I want to set manually, should I use ExtraFieldPropagation.set()? Because when doing so, ```currentSpan.context().extra()``` is populated with the key+value but without the ```baggage-``` prefix and also MDC is not populated with the key+value...

Comment: Without `baggage` however you need to add it to the baggage keys. With the new releases you will have to pass the value explicitly together with `baggage-` prefix. Or let me rephrase it, the `baggage` prefix will not be required anymore.

Comment: I don't follow... The value I want to set manually is present in baggage-keys (e.g. ```requestid```) but when calling ```ExtraFieldPropagation.set(context, "requestid", SomeValue)``` it isn't added to MDC (Problem) and it is in ```currentSpan.context().extra()``` but without the baggage- prefix (Is it how it is supposed to be?) and if it's suppose to be without the baggage- prefix in the context, will the prefix be added to the request when the code calls another service via HTTP or message?

Comment: It will be added to headers with the prefix but without it it will be in the mdc. Sometimes it's not flushed to mdc. You can read about it in the documentation of the new sleuth version. There you can set the auto flush option

Answer (score 1):

You can write customeFilter to intercept every request and put data from request into MDC.

```
@Component
public class CustomFilter implements Filter {

  @Override
  public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res,
      FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
      final String correlationId = getCorrelationIdFromHeader(req);
      MDC.put(HttpConstants.CORRELATION_ID_HEADER_NAME, correlationId);
      chain.doFilter(req, res);
  }
}
```

Comment: I was looking for something automatic provided by the framework, not to manually do it

Answer (score 0):

Just do

```
    public String someMethod(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse httprespons)
{
 MDC.put(request.getHeader("header_name"););
}
```

pass HttpServletRequest,HttpServletResponse as parameter.

Comment: I was looking for something automatic provided by the framework, not to manually do it